# Spring 4 WebApplicationInitializer log4j2 multiple initialization issues

Tags: java, spring, log4j2

I am building an application using 100% code configuration approach for a spring 4 web app. Following is my web config class.

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends Log4jServletContainerInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {


    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(null, container);

        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(MyAppContext.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        webContext.register(MyServletContext.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dynamic = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(webContext));
        dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dynamic.addMapping("/api/*");
    }
}
```

Problem -

a. My spring beans are getting initialized twice

b. Whenever I add logj2.xml in my resources (using maven), then my bean creation fails.

I am new to this, kindly help me.

Log4J - 2.5, Tomcat - 8.0.32

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. It was not the problem with WebApplInitializer but with Spring Java Configurations files. I was maintaining separate configs for ApplicationContext and ServletContext. In ApplicationContext, using

```
@ComponentScan(value = "com.application.module", 
excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(value = {Configuration.class})})
```

did the trick.

In servlet context, I used -

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = AppContext.class)
```